# why python add '\' character when we call splitlines on a string?

Tags: python-2.7

I am calling splitlines on follwing string.

```
'ab\cd'.splitlines()
```

the output which I am getting is

```
['ab\\cd']
```

so why python adds one more '\' to this string.

Answer (score 1):

It has nothing to do directly with `splitlines`. 
It's just happen that `splitlines` returns a list, and when printing a list Python uses the `repr` of each object, which needs to escape the `\`.

```
string = 'a\c'
print repr(string)
>> 'a\\c'
```